# Google Cloud Shell is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting in a few minutes

Tags: web-applications, google-cloud-platform

Cloud Shell would not start and come up with message

"Google Cloud Shell is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting in a few minutes."

I have been getting this message for the last 4 days now. I know that this is beta and has no SLA whatsoever, but as anyone seen this or know how to fix it? 
All help is very appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

The error you have received can be due to advanced configuration changes made to your shell, such as:

- Modifying their .bashrc or other shell configuration files.
- Storing unusually large amounts of data in their home disk.
- Adding some programs to automatically start up on login.

You can try to restart the Cloud shell and see if that resolve your issue. This can be done by going through Setting button on top right of your Cloud shell and selecting Restart Cloud Shell from the list.